# Overload operator '<<' without output streaming intentions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm new to operators overloading and I'm facing this challenge:

I have this class `Ticket` and i'm creating 2 objects `Ticket`, `ticket1` and `ticket2`. Each ticket has a number of suitcases, I store that ids into a vector named `id_suitcases`.

Now I want to be able to add several suitcaseID's to that vector using operator `<<`

eg.

**Output:**

```
19/20 NORMAL
Xico da Tina | Passaport: 2511 | Company: TAP
Suitcases: 120  20  35  50

Jussara Barlabe | Passaport: 7471231 | Company: Jato do Bob
Suitcases: 120  20  35  50
```

**Using Operator << like this**

```
ticket1 << 455 << 73 <<  9;
ticket2 <<  55 << 83 << 32;
```

**Output:**

```
After add suitcases to passenger
Xico da Tina | Passaport: 2511 | Company: TAP
Suitcases: 120  20  35  50  455  73  9

Jussara Barlabe | Passaport: 7471231 | Company: Jato do Bob
Suitcases: 120  20  35  50  55  83  32
```

**Class Ticket**

```
class Ticket {
    std::string passenger;
    int passport;
    std::string& company;
    std::vector<int> id_suitcases;
public:

    Ticket(std::string cliente, int passId, std::string& comp, std::vector<int> suitcases) :company(comp)
    {
        passenger = cliente;
        passport = passId;
        id_suitcases = suitcases;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, const Ticket& b)
    {
        output << b.passenger << " | Passaport: " << b.passport << " | Company: " << b.company << std::endl;
        output << "Suitcases: ";
        for (auto suitcase : b.id_suitcases)
            output << suitcase << "  ";
        return output;
    }

    bool operator << (int suitcaseID)
    {
        for (auto suitcase : id_suitcases)
            if (suitcaseID == suitcase)
            {
                return false;
            }
        id_suitcases.push_back(suitcaseID);
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "19/20 NORMAL\n";
    std::vector<int> suitcases;
    suitcases.push_back(120);
    suitcases.push_back(20);
    suitcases.push_back(35);
    suitcases.push_back(50);

    std::string company1 = "TAP";
    std::string company2 = "Jato do Bob";

    Ticket ticket1("Xico da Tina", 2511, company1, suitcases);
    Ticket ticket2("Jussara Barlabe", 7471231, company2, suitcases);

    std::cout << ticket1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << ticket2 << std::endl;


    ticket1 << 455;
    ticket1 << 73;
    ticket1 << 9;
    ticket2 << 55;
    ticket2 << 83;
    ticket2 << 32;

    //ticket1 << 455 << 73 <<  9; // <-------- Warnings here
    //ticket2 <<  55 << 83 << 32; // <-------- Warnings here

    std::cout << "\nAfter add suitcases to passenger" << std::endl;

    std::cout << ticket1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << ticket2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The main problem is, when i add suitcase by suitcase it works, but if i try to add several suitcases at once this warnings appear:

**Warnings**

```
Warning C4552   '<<': result of expression not used
Warning C4293   '<<': shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
Warning C26452  Arithmetic overflow: Left shift count is negative or greater than or equal to the operand size which is undefined behavior (io.3).
```

It's there a way to disable default `<<` operator or i'm implementing the overload in a bad way?!
Ignore the fact that 2 passengers have repeted suitcasesID's.

Comment: If the `suitcaseID`s should be unique, you could use a `set` or an `unordered_set` instead. Btw, I can't read that picture. Please put it in the question as text instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for that tip but that's not my struggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator<<` cannot chain:

> ```
> bool operator << (int suitcaseID)
>     {
>         for (auto suitcase : id_suitcases)
>             if (suitcaseID == suitcase)
>             {
>                 return false;
>             }
>         id_suitcases.push_back(suitcaseID);
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

Consider that

```
ticket1 << 455 << 73 <<  9;
```

is a different way of writing

```
ticket1.operator<<(455).operator<<(74).operator<<(9);
```

Chaining is the reason you return the reference to the `ostream` in your `friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, const Ticket& b)`.

Return a refeference to the `Ticket` to enable chaining:

```
Ticket& operator << (int suitcaseID)
    {
        for (auto suitcase : id_suitcases)
            if (suitcaseID == suitcase)
            {
                return *this;
            }
        id_suitcases.push_back(suitcaseID);
        return *this;
    }
```

I think you didnt use the returned value anyhow. For a container that should contain only unique elements you can use a `std::set`.

Comment: @Droopy btw don't worry about "no streaming intentions", actually it was the streams that stole `<<` from bitshifts which is the original meaning.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to use

```
ticket1 << 455 << 73 <<  9;
```

The `operator<<` overload must return a referene to the object.

In stead of

```
bool operator << (int suitcaseID) { ... }
```

Use

```
Ticket& operator<< (int suitcaseID)
{
    for (auto suitcase : id_suitcases)
        if (suitcaseID == suitcase)
        {
            return *this;
        }
    id_suitcases.push_back(suitcaseID);
    return *this;
}
```

Your reason to return a `bool` makes some sense but if you are not going to use the return value, it does not add any value to your program.

Answer (score 2):

Look at how `std::ostream::operator<<` are implemented.

The trick is to make the operators actually return a reference to the first operand.

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(...) { ... return *this; }
```

This way, you are given an object that you can call the operator on again, essentially chaining them.